# Adding series to OxyPlot chart programmatically: nothing displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm trying to use OxyPlot in a scenario where I'm setting up the chart type, and then adding 1 or more series to it programmatically. To this end:

- in the XAML view, I simply add a `PlotView` control.
- in the code, my class has a `PlotModel` property (notifying changes), and an `AddSeries` method. Whenever this is invoked, I setup the plot model if not yet configured (I create a new `PlotModel` object and add a `LinearAxis`), create a random data `LineSeries`, and add it to the `Series` collection of the plot model. Finally, I invoke `InvalidatePlot(true)` on it to force it to redraw.

Yet, nothing is displayed when I execute this code, which raises no error.

I googled around a bit but the only code samples I found refer to the typical scenario where a XAML view binds to a bound datasource; but here I'm recreating the PlotModel each time, according to the chart type and series count. You can find a dummy repro solution here: http://1drv.ms/1R8EFBc . Just compile and run, and click Add series. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound property `PlotModel` is never updated due to:

```
private void SetupPieChart()
{
    if (_plot == null) _plot = new PlotModel();
    else _plot.Axes.Clear();
}
```

Change to following and it should work:

```
private void SetupPieChart()
{
    if (PlotModel == null) PlotModel = new PlotModel();
    else PlotModel.Axes.Clear();
}
```

Since :

```
private PlotModel _plot;
public PlotModel PlotModel
{
    get { return _plot; }
    set
    {
        _plot = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // <=== update here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, blame on me :), had not noticed that, sorry for asking :)

Comment: @Naftis can you post your codes in creating a Chart Sir?

Comment: In my case I'm using a MVVM framework (Caliburn Micro) and creating the PlotModel in the VM code, which exposes it as an observable property. The view just has a Plot control with its Model property bound, like Model="{Binding Path=PlotModel,Mode=OneWay}". The VM code is very simple, but too long to be posted as a comment: please find it at http://pastebin.com/1EV1cV6D.